# How to load and validate timestamp data in multiple formats?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am populating table data from a file using the `copy` command. The table includes timestamp data in multiple formats. I have set `alter session set TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24.mi.ss.ff6';` which handles the formatting of certain values thus formatted, but there are other timestamp values in the source file that are formatted differently. To cope with this I am doing e.g.

```
copy into <table> (
     <timestamp_column_1>,
     <timestamp_column_2>
...
) from (
SELECT
    $1,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(t.$2, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

This works, but the `validate` command does not support transformations, so my current validation method is unrealiable.

Is there a way I can achieve what I want in my load without using transformations?

Comment: One quick options is to set the datatype of the staging table column where you are copying the file to be Char or Varchar. Once the data is loaded into snowflake, then you can change the columns to time stamp.